# Pybandit to allow B311: pseudo-random generators to be used in tests

Tags: python, bandit, bandit-python

I've used `random.choice` for tests. And Bandit is showing warnings.

```
x = random.choice(lists)
```

I know I could use `# nosec` comment to suppress the warning. But it would be inconvinent to do it in all lines

```
x = random.choice(lists)  # nosec
```

I want to allow random for file with `tests_*.py` using `.bandit` configuration files. I've found from other samples that you can do it for things like asserts like:

.bandit

```
assert_used:
    skips: ['test.py$', '^test_*.py']
```

So is there any way for **B311** ?

Answer (score 0):

This is okay according to `python -m bandit -r test`

```py
def test_fuzz():  # nosec
    for i in range(10):
        length = random.randint(0, 200)
```

If you don't want to label a line (which allows `# nosec B311`) or function with `# nosec` which also ignores `B101`, use `--skips`:

`python -m bandit --skip B311 -r test`

Maybe `python -m pip install --upgrade bandit` as 1.7 supports `pyproject.toml` though not by default so `python -m bandit -r test --config pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.bandit]
skips = ["B101", "B311"]
```

`pyproject.toml` replaces `setup.cfg` in at least Visual Studio Code, so you might prefer `python -m bandit -r test --ini setup.cfg`:

```ini
[bandit]
skips = B101,B311
```

YAML's nesting allows configuration per test plugin, as you noted. Unfortunately B311 is not a plugin, but i've filed an [enhancement request](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/issues/943) for that.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Python 3.6 or above then, in general, use the "secrets" library rather than the "random" library.

From the documentation *The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.*

Whilst you might not need cryptographically strong random numbers for your tests, it's likely that it will not hurt either, unless your random number generated is seeded.

Seeding the random number generator will ensure that the random number generator emits the same random numbers on each run. This ensures your tests are reproducible. This is usually desirable.

If for some reason you do want to use truly random numbers then use secrets and bandit will not have a problem with it, and it avoids any special bandit configuration.

Comment: The `secrets` module does not support seeds; without seeds, random numbers are not reproducible; and non-reproducible tests are bad.

Comment: I agree, if that is what the OP needs, but seeds and reproducibility aren't mentioned as requirements. I'll update the answer with reproducibility advice.

Answer (score -2):

You can skip it adding `#nosec` to the code.

Or You can skip the B311 using the `--skip` argument to the command line.